# Meaning of 'kerbstone English'

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

In George Bernard Shaw's Pygmalion, the notetaker quoted

"You see this creature with her kerbstone English: the English that will keep her in the gutter to the end of her days."

I understand that Eliza speaks with a Cockney accent typical of East-Londoners. However, what does 'kerbstone English' mean?

All Google searches come up with results that define 'kerbstone', but not 'kerbstone English' as a phrase.

Edit:

Most comments and answers are focusing on the literal meaning and connection between 'gutter' and 'kerbstone'. However, I want to know if 'kerbstone English' has a deeper meaning, such as being the name of an accent, Cockney, for example.

Comment: The explanation is right there: _the English that will keep her in the gutter to the end of her days._ If you look up kerbstone in a dictionary, surely you can see the link between kerbstones and the gutter she is being kept in?

Comment: It's a metaphorical usage akin to 'gutter press', but one which has not become idiomatic.

Comment: No there's no deeper meaning.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase needs to be read in its wider context.

The scene is the opening one of the play and we are being introduced to the characters, when Higgins' is first noticed by the others present Eliza panics that he is a policeman, because he is taking notes. She is worried that she is in trouble for having spoken to a gentleman and says:

> 'I ain't done nothing wrong by speaking to the gentleman. I've a right to sell flowers if I keep off the kerb.'

So the reference to the kerb in relation to Eliza's social position is initially introduced by Eliza in a very literal sense.

The scene is structured to contrast the layers of London society in a situation where the weather has forced a cross-section of them into closer-than-usual proximity as they take shelter. This setting allows Higgins to show of his skills in phonetics identifying people's origins and thereby their status. Higgins use of 'Kerbstone English' is therefore in contrast to the English of Harrow and Cambridge and the English of the drawing room. The Kerb defines Eliza's sociological sphere.

Comment: I can't bring myself to downvote, but I must say that lit crit is off-topic.

Comment: I don't believe this to be lit crit, it's an explanation of the meaning in context of the phrase the OP asked about.

Comment: But it's not a standard phrasing: 'we simply have two words being used in succession' as Max Williams says, and thus the question asks for the interpretation of an idiosyncratic string in a specific piece of literature.

Comment: So what should be done in a situation where someone asks an apparently on-topic question, 'what't the meaning of x phrase', if the *answer* falls into off-topic areas? I looked at the tag 'meaning-in-context' and it seemed to allow for both the Q and the A, though the Q isn't tagged with it. Would it help if I added that tag?

Comment: The ELU model isn't intended to look at DIY candidate-words and nonce word pairings. It looks at standard usages. LiteratureSE is intended for interpretation, unusual constructs, unusual styles....

Answer (score 2):

A kerb is the edge of a pavement (AmE sidewalk). The gutter is the channel at the side of the roadway (see  [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gutter)). "Kerbstone English" relates to what he is going to say in the second part of the sentence.

Comment: It's worth pointing out, in case it's not obvious, that "Kerbstone English" is not a phrase in the English lexicon: we simply have two words being used in succession, rather than a reference to an existing phrase.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't have any special meaning; it's just an expression coined by Professor Higgins to relate to the idea of  being 'in the gutter'.

Comment: If it 'doesn't have any special meaning' (ie it's non-idiomatic), it's off-topic as literary interpretation. And the above is merely general reference.